# Slide out menu bar on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, css

I'm trying to have a menu bar (.top-bar) on top slide out when you click an arrow (#hide), so the arrow  would also need to slide up. In addition to that, the arrow would need to switch (from up arrow to down arrow).
This is what I tried with no luck:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".top-bar").animate({'top': '-=100px'}, 1000);
    $("#hide").animate({'top': '-=100px'}, 1000);
    $(".close").switchClass('close', 'open', [1000]);
},
function(){
    $(".top-bar").animate({'top': '+=100px'}, 1000);
    $("#hide").animate({'top': '+=100px'}, 1000);
    $(".open").switchClass('open', 'close', [1000]);
});
 });
```

Comment: Grillz is right. If someone answers your question make sure to accept that answer so that they get credit for helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a JS Fiddle that should help you out. Take a look over it and if you have any questions comment on this post and I'll respond. The first column has no children, so there is no slide. Use columns 2 and 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/GvGoldmedal/Vqkvu/

Comment: Sorry I couldn't respond sooner. Thanks for the demo, but I think I found what I was looking for here: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html  I do have a question, though: will .slideToggle not work if the element's position is set to absolute in the css?